# How do I get the XML namespace value with a Windows batch?

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

I have the following XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<Document xmlns="a:b:c:d:e" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Test>
        ...
    </Test>
</Document>
```

I would like to know how can I extract the XML namespace value (xmlns, not xmlns:xsi) with a batch file : **a:b:c:d:e**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What kind of batch file? What O/S platform?

Comment: Windows, I'm going to edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: use grep:  http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Comment: There is no native method to read and write XML files with a batch file. You can certainly use a brute force method to do it but it is highly dependent on the data being formatted the same way every time.  Use a scripting language that has a native method to read and write XML. Jscript, Vbscript, Powershell, Python, etc..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a batch file example leveraging `PowerShell`:

```bat
@Set "xmlns="
@For /F %%A In ('Powershell -C "[xml]$fC=GC 'source.xml';"$fC.Document.xmlns"'
) Do @Set "xmlns=%%A"
@If Defined xmlns Echo [%xmlns%] && Pause
```

*Change `source.xml` to your specific `.xml` file name
Also bear in mind that you may need to ensure that your `cmd.exe` instance is capable of outputting the character set for `ISO-8859-15`, possibly `codepage 28605`.*